# how to fetch the last inserted (datetime) records for each category in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to fetch the last inserted (datetime) records for each category in database table

like:

```
select top 1 from table1, table2

where condition1 ...

and condition2 = case when (@var1 = null) then table2.condition2 else @var1
```

-- for all categories if a specific one is not passed

```
order by Creation_Date
```

Any help is appreciated (esp. sample code). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use analytical functions

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY Creation_Date DESC) RN, *
  FROM table
  WHERE condition1
) T
WHERE T.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`, like

```
SELECT
  MAX(Creation_Date),
  Category
FROM table
GROUP BY Category
```

to exclude any records in "future" add `Creation_Date < your_max_date` condition into `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
SELECT MAX(Creation_date), category
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE condition1 ..
GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 0):

This will let you return the full record.  You need to be careful with GROUP BY, as it will return the MAX date, but will return the record which is encountered first in the table.

```
SELECT MAX(a.dtm_created),a.*
FROM (
       SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE someconditions 
       ORDER BY table1.dtm_created DESC) AS a
GROUP BY a.category
```

Comment: Proper RDBMS won't let you to have fields in select list which arent in group by (or agregates).